# Give arguments in geometry to show that!

Tags: calculus, integration

Give arguments in geometry to show that: $\frac{1}{x+1}< \int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{1}{t}dt< \frac{1}{x};\ x> 0.$

could you help me to prove these? Give arguments to show those.

thank you

Comment: Observe the value of the function on the interval $[x,x+1]$ and that the length of the interval is $1$.

Comment: Texify your equation please.

Comment: \frac{1}{x+1}< \int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{1}{t}dt< \frac{1}{x}, x> 0. Troy Woo?

Comment: user, what about 1/t dt?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve your inequality, you can exploit the fact that $\frac{1}{t}$ is a convex function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence:

> $$\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}}<\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}<\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\tag{1}$$

and both the LHS and the RHS improve the previous ones. To prove the original inequality it is sufficient to notice that $\frac{1}{t}$ is a decreasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence the middle term of $(1)$ is between $\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{dt}{x+1}=\frac{1}{x+1}$ and $\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{dt}{x}=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: could you show me how you got 1/2 in 1/(x+1/2) and 1/2(1/x + 1/(x+1)?

Comment: For any positive and convex function $f(t)$, the area under the graphics between $x$ and $x+1$ is upper bounded by the area of the trapezoid having vertices in $(x,f(x)),(x+1,f(x+1)),(x,0),(x+1,0)$, that is the RHS.

Comment: In such a case, Jensen's inequality (midpoint convexity) also gives a lower bound in terms of the value of $f$ in the midpoint of $(x,x+1)$.

Comment: could you please write the solution completely, the RHS and the LHS, from the start till the last? Please, help me n thank u so much!

Answer (score 2):

In this case geometric arguments most probably 
mean relations between the areas:

[image]

We have a relation between the areas: $S_{ABCF}<S_{ABCE}<S_{ABDE}$, where
\begin{align}
S_{ABCF}&=1\times|BC|=\frac{1}{x+1}, \\
S_{ABCE}&=\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{1}{t}dt, \\
S_{ABDE}&=1\times|AE|=\frac{1}{x}.
\end{align}